# How to compute the electronic energy reported by Gaussian from the AlphaOrbitalEnergies

Tags: import, chemistry

I followed the instructions on https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/FCHK.html to analyze the fchk file.

Ran an energy calculation on Gaussian , converted the results to .fchk files. The .fchk files were imported to Mathmatica . I extracted the AlphaOrbitalEnergies from MetaInformation provided in the .fchk files. I am curious to know if there is a way to compute the electronic energy reported by Gaussian from the AlphaOrbitalEnergies.

For my example calculation of methane with HF/3-21G, the Electronic energy is -39.976406 Hartrees

I tried adding up all the energies from AlphaOrbitalEnergies, however, i get -2.18778 Hartrees Next, I tried to only add the energies of occupied orbitals and I got the value of -13.7344 Hartress Does anybody know how to obtain the Electronic Energy from the Alpha Orbital Energy?
[image: Methane notebook example]

Comment: Do you know for certain it *is* possible to get the total energy from the orbital energies? There is a lot of information in a formatted checkpoint file that isn't returned from `Import`